# General error: 1005 Can't create table `chatbot`.`staistic_students` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: laravel, migration

When I do migration in laravel project, it throw such a error: Can't create table `chatbot`.`staistic_students` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `staistic_students` add constraint `staistic_students_right_answers_stu_foreign` foreign key (`right_answers_stu`) references `user_right_answers` (`id`))

that is my migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('staistic_students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('chapters_id');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
            $table->decimal('correct_rate_stu');
            $table->foreignId('right_answers_stu')->constrained('user_right_answers');
            $table->foreignId('wrong_answers_stu')->constrained('user_wrong_answers');
        });
    }
```

that is my table

```
class StatisticStudent extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','chapters_id','correct_rate_stu','right_answers_stu','wrong_answers_stu'
    ]; 
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

```
class UserRightAnswer extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','user_id','answers_id','chapters_id','right_answers_stu'
    ]; 
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

```
class UserWrongAnswer extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','user_id','answers_id','chapters_id','wrong_answers_stu'
    ]; 
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

the table statistic_students is base on table user_right_answers an table user_wrong_answers

And I think the name is right written, however it didn't work always throw a error: Foreign Key Constraint is incorrectly

Can anyone help?

and this is migration from the other table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_right_answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('user_answers');
            $table->foreignId('answers_id')->constrained('user_answers');
            $table->foreignId('chapters_id')->constrained('questions');
            $table->integer('right_answer_stu');
        });
    }

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_wrong_answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('user_answers');
            $table->foreignId('answers_id')->constrained('user_answers');
            $table->foreignId('chapters_id')->constrained('questions');
            $table->integer('wrong_answer_stu');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Typo: `staistic_students`

Comment: it still doesn't work ,when I changed it

Comment: Can you share code for migrations of 'user_right_answers' and 'user_wrong_answers' table? I think issue is related to primary key column in these two tables.

Comment: sure, as u can see I uploaded the migration